# Is it Possible to have a Blueprint CSS of 1000px width?

Tags: blueprint-css

I designed my layout in 1000px. Is it possible to work with Blueprint CSS? Tutorials say 950px is the maximum width of a blueprint.  Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4):

http://bluecalc.groupion.com/ will help you generate a grid.css file suitable for your layout width.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any maximum width you want. It may not look great on all monitors, but that's your call.

Comment: Hi Michael it will not possible but you can increase cells of total you may get it.. the Solutions Means present we have 24x40px=960px; if you increase 26cell you will may get good results.. Its just try don't think bad.. All the Best